# Run migration script via Controller Symfony2

Tags: symfony

There are 2 databases used in a Symfony2 project and there is a migration script which is placed at location

```
app/DoctrineMigrations/codes/Version20150914201128.php
```

This migration is not for default database, its for the second database used.

There is a need to run migration script on user selection. On some action a pop-up will open and if a user selects "Yes" then only I need to run that migration script.

**So is it possible or correct way to run migration script via Controller or Service in Symfony2?**

Comment: Can you more explain your issue or your objective please ? I don't understand you

Comment: @darkomen I have updated my question. Please check now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this example. You can trigger the doctrine migrations command easily from a controller-action.

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class SpoolController extends Controller
{
    public function migrateAction($entity_manager = 'default')
    {
        $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->setAutoExit(false);

        $input = new ArrayInput(array(
           'command' => 'doctrine:migrations:migrate',
           '--em' => $entity_manager,
        ));
        // You can use NullOutput() if you don't need the output
        $output = new BufferedOutput();
        $application->run($input, $output);

        // return the output, don't use if you used NullOutput()
        $content = $output->fetch();

        // return new Response(""), if you used NullOutput()
        return new Response($content);
    }
}
```

This slightly changed example was taken from the docs chapter **[How to trigger a Command from a Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/command_in_controller.html)**.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into this example. But as mentioned there are 2 databases so how to choose database using this?

Comment: you can use `--em` option of the `doctrine:migrations:migrate` command. Then just set up multiple entity managers ... one for each database. How to do this would be a separate question.

Comment: Just take a look at the `doctrine.orm.entity_managers` config directive in the DoctrineBundle's [configuration reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html). It's quite easy to understand.

Comment: Instead of using --em name can I pass a new entity manager created as below : `$newEntityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create(
                    $new_connection,
                    $codesConf->getConfiguration(),
                    NULL
            );`

Comment: Is it possible to do as above?

Comment: you'd need to register this newly created entity-manager with doctrine, then use the `--em` flag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100656/discussion-between-ankiig-and-nifr).

Answer (score 1):

The Process Component could be a solution:

```
// .../someController

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class someController extends Controller
{
   public function someAction()
   {
        $process = new Process('php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate 20150914201128');
        $process->run();

       /.../
   }
}
```

Comment: This might work ... but booting the kernel again though you have direct access to it inside the controller is probably not a good solution.

Comment: And what about execute a migration inside a controller?

Comment: Actually how to do it inside a controller is what the question asks for. Good solution ... no. `kernel.terminate` event-listener would be suitable (simple) or sending to some kind of message queue (advanced).